# Set password on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scripting, password

I need to set up a large number of local user accounts on a number of machines running Ubuntu, and I need a way to script the password setting. These machines use /etc/shadow, as is the default in the installation. **passwd** doesn't take a password as argument, and **usermod** wants the password in encrypted form.

The best way I have found is to write a separate C program to use **crypt** to encrypt the passwords, and then use usermod to set them in /etc/shadow.

But is there some other way I can script password setting like this, that at least doesn't require me to do parts of it in C? It seems to me there must be some command I don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man newusers

read [this](http://linux.die.net/man/8/newusers) and [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-create-multiple-users-accounts-in-batch.html)

Comment: Ah, so there *was* a command for this that I didn't know about. Thanks!